# Push notificaton without device token

Tags: iphone, objective-c, push-notification, push

My application is in Appstore now and ı cant find out device tokens.is it possible to send push notification without device token

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: No, sorry.

Longer answer: No, you'll need to submit a new binary which collects the device tokens and submits them to your server.

Answer (score 0):

You really should have sorted all of this out during testing with the sandbox before releasing to the AppStore!

The device will send your server a token to indicate that it wants to receive notifications. It is up to your server to store these tokens and send the appropriate messages to the devices as and when required.

Your server should also respond to people requesting to not have notifications any further and also for tokens that have become "inactive".